# Dynamic programming algorithm to place blocks in a given area

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

You basically have an area with the dimensions 4 × n. Find the number of different ways you can fill this area with blocks that each have the dimensions 1 × 2. You are allowed to rotate the smaller blocks.

My code is below.  Its basically a big recursive function.  Iterates through the matrix (4 x n) then places a block (if possible) going to the right (horizontal) and places a block going down (vertical).  Each matrix[i][j] will run recursively trying to determine possible different ways to place a block with the remaining area, and so on.  Whats the right time complexity for my algo? O(n^2)?

My algorithm is not fast enough.  Was wondering if anyone can provide a different approach to solve the problem.  Probably using dynamic programming, to minimize repetitive computations.

These are some of the answers I've achieved so far.  They are definitely right, but 'n' can go up to 21 which will take my program quite some time.

Answers:

```
4x1: 1
4x2: 5
4x3: 11
4x4: 36
4x5: 95
4x6: 281
4x7: 781
4x8: 2245
4x9: 6336
4x10: 18061
4x11: 51205
4x12: 145601
4x13: 413351
4x14: 1174500
4x15: 3335651
```

Code:

```
def Blocks(n):
    maximum = 4*n

    def answerAcquired(counter,result):
        if counter == maximum:                        
            result[0] += 1
            return True
        return False

    def movePointer(matrix,r,c):
        if c + 1 < n:
            if matrix[r][c+1] == False:
                return False, r, c + 1               ## MOVE POINTER RIGHT
            else:
                return movePointer(matrix,r,c+1)
        elif r + 1 < 4:
            if matrix[r+1][0] == False:
                return False, r + 1, 0               ## MOVE POINTER DOWN
            else:
                return movePointer(matrix, r+1,0)   
        else:
             return True, r, c                       ## END OF MATRIX

    def recur(matrix,r,c, counter,result):

        if answerAcquired(counter,result):
            print("----------------------")
            for row in matrix:
                print(row)
            return
        end, r, c = movePointer(matrix, r,c)
        if end: return

        if c+1 < n and matrix[r][c+1] == False:         ## PLACE RIGHT
            matrix2 = [[c for c in r] for r in matrix]
            matrix2[r][c] = 'R'
            matrix2[r][c+1] = "R"
            recur(matrix2, r, c, counter+2, result)

        if r+1 < 4 and matrix[r+1][c] == False:         ## PLACE DOWN
            matrix2 = [ [c for c in r] for r in matrix ]
            matrix2[r + 1][c] = "D"
            matrix2[r][c] = "D"
            recur(matrix2, r, c, counter+2, result)

    r,c,counter, result = 0,-1, 0, [0]
    matrix = [ [ False for y in range(n) ] for x in range(4)]
    recur(matrix,r,c,counter,result)
    return result[0]

print("Answer:",Blocks(5))
```

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664113/count-the-ways-to-fill-a-4-times-n-board-with-dominoes

Comment: The first large problem is that your code doesn't execute.  Your line `matrix2 = [[c for c in r] for r in matrix]` fatally alters the values of `r` and `c`.

Comment: In general, this level of question belongs on the math site, not here.